# ScrollTo method doesn't work in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I use scroll in my method

```
const scrollToCenter = () => {
 const kon = document.querySelector('.clazz');
 const width = kon.offsetWidth;
 kon.scrollTo(width / 2, 0);
 };
```

and it works fine in Chrome and Mozilla. In the Edge I'd got an error "Object doesn't support property or method scrollTo".
Is exist any different method to use it in Edge?

Comment: Looks like this is a confirmed bug in Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/

Comment: Maybe you can use `scrollIntoView` instead?

Comment: I change it on the scrollIntoView - firstly, it work and app doesn't break. I'll test in on another browsers and if it works correctly, so it will be the solve on my question. Thanks.

Comment: You can also probably simulate this with `Window.scrollTo`: [JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/biyajanuqa/edit?html,output).

Comment: [THIS](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) Polyfill fixed the issue for my angular application

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The official report :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/

The issue has been assigned to someone.

Following the comments the workaround is

"
`.scrollTop = 0` instead of `.scrollTo(0,0)` In case you want to scroll somewhere else than top i haven’t found a workaround "

Comment: To scroll to the bottom I used `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight` and it works

Comment: Can't find the page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I change it on the scrollIntoView - firstly, it work and app doesn't break. I'll test in on another browsers and if it works correctly, so it will be the solve on my question.

k-nut's answer was correct.